# According Dropdown Menu using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i need to create according dropdown menu like us follow.

[image]

In suppage, the slide must be open.

for example, if i click the Services 2, in Services 2 page the slide will be open. Services 2 will be as selected menu.

I have attached my code.

I need, in subpages, the submenu will be open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="droplinetabs.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="droplinemenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

droplinemenu.buildmenu("droplinetabs1")

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="droplinetabs1" class="droplinetabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">About 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Services 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS FILE

```
.droplinetabs{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray; /*underline across bottom of main tabs*/
}

.droplinetabs ul{
    font: bold 11px Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.droplinetabs li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.droplinetabs a{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    background: #c76023 url(leftedge.gif) no-repeat left top; /*default background color of tabs, left corner image*/
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 4px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.droplinetabs a:link, .droplinetabs a::visited, .droplinetabs a:active{
    color: white;
}

.droplinetabs a span{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: transparent url(rightedge.gif) no-repeat right top; /*right corner image*/
    padding: 7px 9px 3px 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.droplinetabs a span{
    float: none;
}


.droplinetabs a:hover{
    background-color: #b05016; /*background color of tabs onMouseover*/
    color: white;
}

.droplinetabs a:hover span{
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Sub level menus*/
.droplinetabs ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #c76023; /*sub menu background color */
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Sub level menu links style */
.droplinetabs ul li ul li a{
    font: normal 13px Verdana;
    padding: 6px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #c76023; /*sub menu background color */
}

.droplinetabs ul li ul li a span{
    background: #c76023; /*sub menu background color */
}

.droplinetabs ul li ul li a:hover{ /*sub menu links' background color onMouseover. Add rounded edges in capable browsers */
    background: #714421;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;  
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

JQUERY FILE

```
var droplinemenu={

arrowimage: {classname: 'downarrowclass', src: 'down.gif', leftpadding: 5}, //customize down arrow image
animateduration: {over: 200, out: 100}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

buildmenu:function(menuid){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var $mainmenu=$("#"+menuid+">ul")
        var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function(i){
            var $curobj=$(this)
            var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions={h:$curobj.find('a:eq(0)').outerHeight()}
            this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false
            if (!this.istopheader)
                $subul.css({left:0, top:this._dimensions.h})
            var $innerheader=$curobj.children('a').eq(0)
            $innerheader=($innerheader.children().eq(0).is('span'))? $innerheader.children().eq(0) : $innerheader //if header contains inner SPAN, use that
            $innerheader.append(
                '<img src="'+ droplinemenu.arrowimage.src
                +'" class="' + droplinemenu.arrowimage.classname
                + '" style="border:0; padding-left: '+droplinemenu.arrowimage.leftpadding+'px" />'
            )

            $curobj.hover(
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    if ($targetul.queue().length<=1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                        if (this.istopheader)
                            $targetul.css({left: $mainmenu.position().left, top: $mainmenu.position().top+this._dimensions.h})
                        if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest) //detect IE6 or less, fix issue with overflow
                            $mainmenu.find('ul').css({overflow: (this.istopheader)? 'hidden' : 'visible'})
                        $targetul.dequeue().slideDown(droplinemenu.animateduration.over)
                },
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    $targetul.dequeue().slideUp(droplinemenu.animateduration.out)
                }
            ) //end hover
        }) //end $headers.each()
        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible', width:$mainmenu.width()})
    }) //end document.ready
}
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: I need, In subpages, the submenu will be open. (That is slideout will be open)

Comment: I suggest this is closed as "too broad". The comments indicate that the text was unclear. and comments under the answer below have turned into a request for free code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at your code. I have to say it is a little bit clumsy as so much styling is hard coded straight into your JavaScript. Ideally you would want to separate as much styling and use classes instead. The absolute positioning of the drop down menus is not really necessary and causes a solution to be a bit more complex.

If you want one of the drop downs to appear automatically you could for example add an on class onto that UL. So say you are on the services page. The Menu would be this instead to reveal the services options:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="droplinetabs.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="droplinemenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

droplinemenu.buildmenu("droplinetabs1")

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="droplinetabs1" class="droplinetabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">About 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
  <ul class="on">
  <li><a href="#">Services 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your JS after all the hiding has happened you can loop through the ULs to check if it has class "on" and it will animate straight away.

So add the following part after the $mainmenu.find("ul").... part

```
    var droplinemenu={

arrowimage: {classname: 'downarrowclass', src: 'down.gif', leftpadding: 5}, //customize down arrow image
animateduration: {over: 200, out: 100}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

buildmenu:function(menuid){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var $mainmenu=$("#"+menuid+">ul")
        var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function(i){
            var $curobj=$(this)
            var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions={h:$curobj.find('a:eq(0)').outerHeight()}
            this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false
            if (!this.istopheader)
                $subul.css({left:0, top:this._dimensions.h})
            var $innerheader=$curobj.children('a').eq(0)
            $innerheader=($innerheader.children().eq(0).is('span'))? $innerheader.children().eq(0) : $innerheader //if header contains inner SPAN, use that
            $innerheader.append(
                '<img src="'+ droplinemenu.arrowimage.src
                +'" class="' + droplinemenu.arrowimage.classname
                + '" style="border:0; padding-left: '+droplinemenu.arrowimage.leftpadding+'px" />'
            )

            $curobj.hover(
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    if ($targetul.queue().length<=1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                        if (this.istopheader){
                            $targetul.css({left: $mainmenu.position().left, top: $mainmenu.position().top+this._dimensions.h})
                        }
                        if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest) //detect IE6 or less, fix issue with overflow
                            $mainmenu.find('ul').css({overflow: (this.istopheader)? 'hidden' : 'visible'})
                        $targetul.dequeue().slideDown(droplinemenu.animateduration.over)
                },
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    $targetul.dequeue().slideUp(droplinemenu.animateduration.out)
                }
            ) //end hover
        }) //end $headers.each()

        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible', width:$mainmenu.width()})
        $($mainmenu.find("ul")).each(function(index) {
            if($(this).hasClass('on')){
                $(this).css({left:$mainmenu.position().left,top:$mainmenu.position().top+$(this).height()})
                $(this).slideDown(droplinemenu.animateduration.over)
            }
        });
    }) //end document.ready
}
}
```

It is not an ideal solution as you should be able to simply do a "display:block" on your on class of that UL but because so much style calculation is going on in your accordion JS this can't be done so easily.
This "hack" should work for you though, I hope it does.

I would advice a more elegant jQuery accordion solution, there are plenty on the web to look at. It looks like you may have been looking at a relatively old example going by the jQuery version you are using.

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to implement this code. please help me. very urgent

Comment: I've copied both files in the answer now. This works for me. There is not much more I can do. Like I said, ideally you would want to use a different accordion menu plugin which is easier to understand. The one you have is too integrated into the styling/html. It's most likely a custom built one, so difficult to understand. Good luck.